# How Integrate HTML Theme In Elgg?

Tags: elgg

I am new in Elgg.

I Have A One Html Theme,

That Theme I Want to Integrate in Elgg,

How To Integrate Theme?

Using Coding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no well defined steps to do that. basically you can not not integrate any external theme to a framework, like Elgg, or Wordpress. Each has its own CSS file and their  they defined classes for button,s header, tabs etc.   names are also different.
So in short, the whole effort is like developing new theme of your own, which look like the HTML theme you have. there is no short cut.